# Почему причастие не относят к прилагательным, а деепричастие к наречиям

Tags: морфология

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, и все объясняется связью с действием.
Но все же почему нельзя задать вопросы, например, так:

Не "что делающий?" — лежащий, а "какой?" — лежащий.

Или же не "что делая?" — посмеиваясь, а "как?" — посмеиваясь.

Лежащий неподалёку странный предмет приманивал своей необычной формой.

Посмеиваясь, он продолжал говорить.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  "Слова «а всё ж(е)», «а всё ж таки», «а всё-таки», стоящие в начале предложения, могут отделяться запятой при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании".  Неужели дело в союзе "но"? На мой взгляд, обособление уместно.

Comment: @Александр: мне такое рваное прочтение кажется очень неестественным. Но если настаиваете, можно вернуть запятую.

Comment: Мы же не знаем, как мыслил автор вопроса. Мне пауза не мешает, а наоборот, предвосхищает вопрос. Я не настаиваю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Почему причастие не относят к прилагательным, а 
  деепричастие к наречиям
```

Потому что это различные части речи, **от их различения зависит их написание и пунктуационное оформление.**

```
Но все же почему нельзя задать вопросы, например, так:
Не "что делающий?" — лежащий, а "какой?" — лежащий.
Или же не "что делая?" — посмеиваясь, а "как?" — посмеиваясь.
```

Почему нельзя? Можно, но нужно понимать, зачем мы задаём эти вопросы. Если для определения синтаксической роли, то какой? как? Если для обозначения части речи, то какой? что делающий? что делая?

Они очень похожи, и в  устной речи нам действительно всё равно - причастие это или прилагательное, деепричастие или наречие, а вот в письменной придётся над этим задуматься, чтобы правильно написать.

Не думаю, что так сложно запомнить, чем они отличаются друг от друга.

Обе части речи образованы от глагола, НО:

— от глаголов **совершенного вида ВСЕГДА образуются причастия**

— от глаголов **несовершенного вида мы получаем причастия, если у них есть зависимое слово(слова)**, то есть налицо причастный оборот.

Глагол ЖАРИТЬ (что делать?) несовершенного вида. Получить от него причастия мы можем только двумя способами:

изменить вид, прибавив приставку: (что сделать?) ПОЖАРИТЬ. Какой бифштекс? ПОЖАРЕННЫЙ

добавить хотя бы одно зависимое слово. ЖАРЕННЫЙ (на чем? в чем?) в масле бифштекс.

Если не менять вида и не добавлять зависимых слов, от глагола ЖАРИТЬ можно получить только прилагательное: ЖАРЕНЫЙ бифштекс.

Обе части речи обозначают признак предмета, НО :

— прилагательное обозначает, скажем так, морфологические, отличительные **признаки предмета**: по росту, цвету, весу, материалу, характеру и т.п.);

— причастие обозначает признак **предмета по действию.**

Сравните. Пожаренный, жаренный в масле бифштекс – это тот, который жарили, т.е здесь признак по действию. Жареный – это отличительный признак бифштекса. Ведь он может быть и сырым, свежим, говяжьим, вкусным, жестким.

Итак, чтобы отличить отглагольное прилагательное от причастия, достаточно сделать предложенные выше несложные шаги.

Как рассуждать при образовании краткой формы прилагательного и причастия?

Здесь есть маленький нюанс. Краткая форма отвечает на вопросы каков? каково? какова? каковы? Проблема с Н и НН может возникнуть, если вы неправильно определите часть речи, ведь у краткого причастия всегда одна Н, а у краткого прилагательного столько, сколько в полной форме.

Теперь у нас есть безошибочный способ определить часть речи, НО:

В русском языке есть такой способ образования слов, как переход одной части речи в другую. Самый простой пример всем  хорошо знаком:-Что тебе купить? -Купи мне мороженое.Слово мороженое отвечает на вопрос что? , а значит, обозначает предмет  и принимает на себя все синтаксические функции существительного. Но ведь это же отглагольное прилагательное: морозить – мороженое мясо. Причастие провожающие мы чаще используем  как существительное: (кто?) провожающие стояли на перроне.

Возьмем глагол ВОСПИТАТЬ . Это глагол совершенного вида, значит, мы смело можем получить от него причастие ВОСПИТАННЫЙ (т.е. тот, которого воспитали).

Пример. Девочка, воспитанная в антисанитарных условиях, часто потом болела. Причастие.

И ещё один. Какая воспитанная девочка! Воспитанная, то есть вежливая, скромная, тактичная. прилагательное

Краткое причастие – Н : девочка воспитана в антисанитарных условиях.

Краткое прилагательное – НН, как в полной форме: девочка вежлива, воспитанна, тактична.

**Теперь о деепричастиях.**

Одиночное деепричастие обозначает **добавочное действие**, **легко заменяется глаголом,** от которого образуется: Пошумев, река успокоилась (Б. Полевой). (Пошумела и успокоилась).

Деепричастие может быть совершенного и несовершенного вида, стоит, как правило, перед глаголом-сказуемым: Пуля ударилась в камень и, взвизгнув, отскочила рикошетом (Пуля отскочила, при этом взвизгнула). Обосабливается запятыми.

**При переходе в наречия деепричастие утрачивает значение добавочного, сопутствующего действия, лишается всех глагольных категорий, т.е. значений вида, времени, залога и управления,** не обосабливается.

Деепричастия, перешедшие в наречия, могут входить в состав фразеологических сочетаний: спустя рукава, сложа руки и др.

Наречие **обозначает признак действия, легко заменяется другим наречием**: Мы ехали не останавливаясь по белой равнине. (Ехали быстро).

**В наречие переходят только деепричастия несовершенного вида, стоящие, как правило, после глагола-сказуемого: отвечал не думая.**